# Using methods from other classes

Tags: java, class, object, methods, import

The difference between (a) `import somePackage.someClass;` and (b)`someClass object = new someClass();` is that (a)  will allow call the methods from the imported class without creating new instances of it, while (b) will create an object using the template class and therefore the methods for the class `someClass` will belong to the object `object`. So if I want to use a method `someMethod()` from `someClass` in (b) I'd call it through the `object` object. Is it how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes you can use static methods from a class directly
- Yes you can use methods from a class by creating an object

But more important thing than just the above options available is when to use which. First type of call is to class methods whereas the second class is to instance methods.

Instance Methods vs Class Methods: Each class represents a set of attributes and behaviour. Instance methods usually represent the behaviour. example if Person is a class and Robb is an object, then robb.weight can be attribute, robb.write() would be an instance method and Person.type() (ans: species) or Person.population (ans: total number of instances) can be class methods.

Also you represent instance methods in textual writing as ClassName#instanceMethod and ClassName.classMethods

Answer (score 0):

No, you are wrong

Simplistically if the class that you want to use is not in the same `package` then you need to import it, or fully path the class e.g. `java.util.ArrayList`.

If the methods are not static, then you will need to create a new Instance of the class you want to use.

Comment: But doesn't the second way to do it create a new object?

Answer (score -1):

You can use methods from other class directly only if it is a static method. You will also have to add static in your import statement if you want to use the method name directly without prefixing it will the class name.
For non-static methods you have to create instance of the class and then call that method.

Comment: `you will also have to add static in your import statement.` - wrong, this is only necessary if you want to use the method name directly without prefixing it will the class name

Comment: @scary you are right. Want I wanted to say was `import somePackage.someClass;` should include static keyword which is missing in question. I have edited my answer.